# Form close event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I had an problem with my application closing in c#. When I hit the close button it display twice or more times the message box. What should I do?

```
private void home_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to really exit ? ", 
                            "Exit", 
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                             MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
    else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
    {
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: We probably need more details to answer that. It used to work fine for me. I suppose you added the event delegate more than once and the system calls each one you added.

Comment: In my application I have created three windows forms . I used following code for closing all forms seperately...

Comment: Shouldn't you be using Form**Closing** instead of FormClosed?

Comment: Show the code for how you subscribed to `home_FormClosed`

Comment: code is display above..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use the `Form.FormClosing` event instead of the `FormClosed` event. in the arguments, you find a field `e.Cancel`. by setting this to false, you keep your form open

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I use visual studio 2012 . So there is no keyword 'Cancel' . But that key word was in Visual c# 2012 Express...

Comment: the field has been introduced with .Net 2.0. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs_members(v=vs.80).aspx) so there should be the Cancel property also for visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Form1_FormClosing` event and also don't use `Application.Exit()` like this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var x = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to really exit ? ", 
                             "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (x == DialogResult.No) 
    {
       e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
      e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to really exit ? ", 
              "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the **multiple** prompts by checking to see if `Application.Exit()` has been called already from within the `FormClosing` event:

```
    void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall)
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to really exit ? ", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            }
            else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but in my visual studio c# version said there is no definition or exception method called 'Cancel'... And also it said that I have missing a directive or assembly reference..

Comment: Then it should be there, as FormClosing has been around since .Net 2.0.  Your problem is somewhere else.  Give more details about your project setup and how you are using all the code...

Comment: I changed FormClosed into FormClosing. But there is an error saya that 'no overload for FormClosing in System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler'...

Comment: not yet... Cancel key word is not in my visual studio c# application

Answer (score 0):

Use the form closing event instead.

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        var confirmation = MessageBox.Show("Sure to close form", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (confirmation == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
        {
             e.Cancel = true; //Even cancelled, form will not get closed now
        }
    }
```